# VBA Lookup handling of unknown entries

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, vlookup

I need the vlookup-function for analyzing some data. The problem is that when I get the data (in an excel sheet) from a third-party software there are certain entries for which there is no assigned value (yet). Now I would like to highlight these entries in a certain way (or maybe just make clear that there is an error, much like the formula "vlookup" does) without the macro stopping. 
Any Idea on how to do this?

(I've tried "on error resume next" and the next line assigned a default value to the cell but this caused the vlookup function to fail even if there was an appropriate assignment.)

The current code for the property which is assigned via the vlookup instruction is:

```
Worksheets("S1").Cells(z-1,22).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("S1").Cells(z-1,1).Value, Worksheets("S2").Range("A1:B1000"),2,False)
```

Comment: Maybe a typo in the question, but you'll need to quote the range A1:B1000 for that to work at all i.e. `Range("A1:B1000")`

Comment: exactly correct as Dave said

Comment: you are right, I just messed up while i tried to replicate my code in here (different worksheet-names and so on). Still doesn't solve my problem.